# VW Passat B5 EPC Light on Dashboard

Tags: engine, vw, passat

There is a yellow light on my dash that says 'EPC'. I have no idea what this could mean on my car as I haven't noticed any difference in the way it drives, nor are there any unusual sounds other than from the cam belt which is due for a service in 3000 miles or so.

What could the EPC light mean on my car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPC stands for **Electronic Power Control** ... it's the stability program which can be found on VW's. All manufacturers have different names for it and this is what VW calls theirs.

As for the issue at hand, it means there is a problem with the system. Until you get the codes read which tells you what the issue is, I'm afraid we cannot help you further.

Comment: Okay so you're saying it could be any number of things to do with the electrical system of the car? And the codes I can obtain from the OBDII port on the car would be the ones that you are referring to right?

Comment: It has to do with the traction control/stability program. It could be any number of things having to do with it (ABS, a sensor, what have you). You'll need an OBDII reader which can register ABS, most likely. Most regular ones will not do this, so has to be specific. You can check it with an OBDII scanner, as VW may do things differently.

Comment: okay thank you, I'll update this post when I know more information

Comment: Ask a separate question. That's what we're here for :D

Comment: @MaxGoodridge you should be able to poll the engine computer for the EPC error using VAG-COM